# Creating a New list based on previous List Definition

Tags: 2007, list, custom-list, list-definition, xml

I have a List definition with following files

**Feature.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feature Id="GUID" 
    Title="abc"
    Description="mmmmmmm."
    Version="1.0.0.0"
    Scope="Web"
    Hidden="FALSE"
    DefaultResourceFile="core"    
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <ElementManifests>
        <ElementManifest Location="oooo.xml" />
        <ElementManifest Location="ooooInstance.xml" />
    </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

**oooo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <ListTemplate
        Name="oooo"
        Type="11021"
        BaseType="1"
        OnQuickLaunch="FALSE"
        SecurityBits="11"
        Sequence="110"
        DisplayName="$Resources:ListFeatures,ListDisplayName;"
        Description="$Resources:ListFeatures,ListDescription;"
        Image="/_layouts/images/pp.gif" />
</Elements>
```

**ooooInstance.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"> 
<ListInstance 
    FeatureId="GUID"
    Id="11022"
    OnQuickLaunch ="FALSE"
    TemplateType="11021"
    Title="$Resources:ListFeatures,ListTitle;"
    Url="$Resources:ListFeatures,ListURL;" >
</ListInstance>
</Elements>
```

Now My question is, I want a new version of a list with an additional column

**- What things do I must have to change, If I want to make another List definition for a list with same Name and it will be removing the current List.**

**- What ooooInstance.xml File doing here, as Before I used to have a feature and an element file for a list definition.**

- I just added a Field, Do I need to change anything in Scheme.xml

Comment: If I just change Version number in Feature    and GUID, will it be enough ? as its the same list but with an additional column now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just created another list definition with different GUID ids and definitely a different name otherwise there will be a conflict.

Make sure you don't change default field's GUIDs tho, if you need more help just leave a comment and I will put more explanation.

Hope it helps if someone else came across same problem :)